# How should I use Docker for a Scraping project that utilizes Selenium, Jsoup, and MySQL as the database?

Tags: mysql, docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, server

I have a quite long question, any help would be greatly appreciated. Whenever I ask something on Stack Overflow, nobody responds :S.

The context is as follows:
I have a Java project (using Maven as dependency manager), which utilizes Selenium in combination with Jsoup to make requests to many websites and retrieve data that is subsequently inserted into a MySQL database. (**Windows**)
So far, everything works correctly without any issues on my local PC.

Now I want to set this up in the best possible way on a server. (**Ubuntu Server**)
I have an old PC that I'm going to use as a server for this application. What do I have set up on the server?: Installed Java and Maven, Installed Jenkins, Installed Git
From Jenkins, the code from Git is downloaded correctly.

My intention is to Dockerize as much as possible, but without going too crazy. Now, here is where the doubts start.

- Firstly, I had doubts about how to communicate my code with the database.
  I could have MySQL always active and launch the project from Jenkins with a Maven task, but this wouldn't involve using Docker. So, if I want to use Docker, according to the official documentation, I can create two containers, one for the app and another for MYSQL, and share these Networks. I can share the same network for both containers or connect the network of MYSQL to the script's network or vice versa. Any recommendations on this? Or does everyone see it as correct so far?
- Then, how do I Dockerize my Selenium code (I'm new to Docker)? I have seen several solutions using selenium standalone and selenium server. What does this really mean? How should I change my code? Can I use my WebDriver as it is, or will I have to use a Remote Server? My WebDriver is configured very simply:

  private static void setupChromeDriver() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);

  ```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```

  }

Where do you recommend I start?

**Ultimately, the flow for the Jenkins job would be as follows:**

1.- I launch a Pipeline, this pipeline launches a Job where it runs MySQL in a container (Same network as the next job)
2.- Immediately after for this same pipeline, I launch the Job where my code will actually be executed (Same network as the previous job)
3.- This Job will download the code, create a container where the Script will be launched (under a Maven command)
4.- All containers are closed
**Where I really have doubts is in my step 3.**
If you would be so kind as to help me, any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Any recommendations? **Any explanation of what I should do with my Script to be able to run it in Docker without any problems, remote server or standalone?**
I know the question is very long and may lead to confusion, my English is not perfect, I don't know if I have expressed myself correctly.

**Thank you very much in advance for reading all of this and greetings.**